# Rails Event Listings can't display image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, paperclip

I am trying to display a list of my events in a rails application. I can properly display each event but can't display any of the images associated with them.

[image]

I think it has something to do with the way I'm showing events by month and am not certain how to fix. I'm new to development and would appreciate any help given.

**Event Model**

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base

  self.primary_key = :id
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  attr_accessible :name, :location, :date, :time, :price, :phone, :website, :description, :avatar, :slug, :business_id

  has_attached_file :avatar, 
    styles: {
      thumb:    '100x100>',
      square:   '200x200#',
      medium:   '400x400>',
      full:     '800x800>'
    },
    :default_url => "/assets/avatar-event-blank.png"

  validates_attachment_size :avatar, :less_than => 2.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif']

  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :location, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true

  belongs_to :business
  ...
```

**Event Controller**

Here is my controller where I separate the months and list events grouped by month.

```
...
def index
  @events = Event.all(:select => "name, id, date, slug", :order => "date ASC")
  @event_months = @events.group_by { |t| t.date.beginning_of_month }

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @events }
  end
end
...
```

**Event Index**

```
...
<% @event_months.sort.each do |month, events| %>
  <div class="titlebar">
    <span><%=h month.strftime("%B %Y") %></span>
  </div>
  <ul class="listing-events">
    <% for event in events %>
      <li><a href="/events/<%= event.slug %>" title="<%= event.name %> on <%=event.date.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %>">
        <div class="le-image" style="background-image: url('http://cpd.typepad.com/lighthousestock/images/2007/05/22/baileys_harbor_rear_0181.jpg')">
          <div class="le-avatar">
            <%= image_tag event.business.avatar.url(:full) %>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="le-info">
          <div itemprop="name" class="title"><%= event.name %></div>
          <div class="date"><%= event.date.strftime("%B %e, %Y") %></div>
        </div>
      </a></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% end %>
...
```

Comment: I'm not very familiar with paperclip, but as a debugging technique, I'd start by putting a quick display of the href you're using and make sure it's displaying the link you'd expect.  Just add a line like `<%= event.business.avatar.url(:full) -%>` and make sure the url is what you'd expect.  You can verify the link resolves to an image.  If the url isn't what you'd expect you know that you're probably not using paperclip correctly and then can take a next step in that direction.  You can also just `inspect element` from your browser or view the source to confirm the url too.

Comment: Come to think of it, you might check the syntax of `image_tag` for the line `<%= image_tag event.business.avatar.url(:full) %>` to make sure you're calling it correctly.  A quick check is to replace the paperclip url with a fixed url that you know resolve to be sure any image would display with your syntax.  More of a sanity check than anything.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue after reviewing my code. I had to make sure I was selecting all the attributes that I was trying to use in the controller.

**Events Controller**

```
@events = Event.all(:select => "name, id, date, business_id, avatar_file_name, avatar_updated_at, slug", :order => "date ASC")
```

Comment: Good for you, Justin!   Looks like you're on your way as a developer!